# git: merge changes from main repo in code.google.com

Tags: git

Let's say that I've created a clone http://code.google.com/r/kkowalczyk-leveldb of http://code.google.com/p/leveldb using web interface on code.google.com

Since the time I created my clone, there were changes made to http://code.google.com/p/leveldb and I would like to merge them to my clone, preferably preserving history (i.e. I could merge them manually using a diff/merge tool, but that doesn't preserve git history).

What are the magic commands to perform such merge?

Preferably please provide the complete commands. I imagine it'll involve some combination of git fetch and git merge and remote-tracking branches etc. My problem is not that I can't read man pages for git fetch or merge, I just don't understand them.

**Update:**

Given Lazy Badger's comment below, I've solved half of the issue:

```
git remote add original https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/
```

Creates something called 'original' pointing to the source. I can then do:

```
git pull original master
```

Which fetches and merges changes from original into my branch master. I would, however, to do it in 2 separate steps: as git fetch and git merge $something to merge into my current branch.

However, after git fetch original, I don't know what $something would be. When I do git branch -a, I don't see anything related to my remote original thingy.

What complicates things is that there are 3 branches in original as well.

So, where do data fetched from original go and how should I refer to it in my git merge $something?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: Answer [found here][1], just small googling.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository/4313155#4313155

Comment: Please see the update. Those don't really answer my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found how to add another remote and pull directly from it:

```
git remote add original https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/
git pull original master
```

If you want to do the fetch and merge separately (instead of a single pull command; maybe because you want to inspect what changed before merging it), then you can do that like this:

```
git fetch original         # update refs/remotes/original/*
git merge original/master  # merge refs/remotes/original/master
```

You might inspect the changes before merging with this command:

```
git log --reverse -p original/master@{1}..original/master@{0}
```

Instead of using the above reflog-based revision specification, you could also just copy-and-paste the `oldhash..newhash` revision specification that was output during the fetch.

---

Technically, `git pull remote branch` is closer to this pair of commands:

```
git fetch remote-or-url branch  # grab remote branch and put it in FETCH_HEAD
git merge FETCH_HEAD            # merge it
```

but this pair (and thus also pulling with both a remote and a branch specified) is usually not as nice since it does not update the remote-tracking branches (`refs/remotes/original/*`). The remote+branch invocations of fetch and pull are useful for one-off merges from repositories for which you do not particularly want to keep a full set of remote-tracking branches (i.e. fetching/pulling a merge request from a minor/rare contributor).

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple remotes to a single repository. Once you've got the second remote, you can simply push the changes of the first to the second. For example:

```
git clone <google_URI>
cd <projdir>
git remote add github <github_URI>
git push github master
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - see the update. What I want to know: after git remote add github <github_URI> followed by git fetch github, what is <sth> in git merge <sth>, assuming that github remote has 2 branches, e.g. master and win.

Comment: Chris' answer below shows the shomething: FETCH_HEAD or original/master would do. Or you could create another local branch from either of the two, and merge from there.